# Using concat for requesting Data from DB and if it empty fetch from Service not working?

Tags: android, persistence, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

I need to request from local storage and if it's empty I should request to Service and store in DB ,but if the DB isn't empty I should ignore the second part.
I'm using Room persistence DB 
(  Flowable), I mean if I store in DB , I could listen to changes .
I'm using concat but neighter of the parts are working

```
 val item1 = itemDao.loadItem(id)
 val item2 = apiIcaSeResource
    .fetchItem(offerId)
    .toFlowable()
    .doOnNext { item ->itemDao.saveItem(Item(...) }


 Flowable.concat(item1, item2)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({
      //          items ->
    }, {
      Timber.e(it, "Error reading items")
    })

  @Query("SELECT * FROM offer WHERE id = :offerId")
 fun loadItem( offerId: String): Flowable<Item>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  fun saveItem(items: Item)


  @GET("item/{itemId}")
 Single<Item> fetchItem(@Path("itemId") Long itemId);
```

Comment: Please have a look at Den Lews post about multiple sources: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/ . I think your solutions is stuck at item1 not finishing, so it could not switch over to item2. You may put a "first" operator after concat, in order to take the first value. Just have a look at post from Dan Lew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM offer WHERE id = :offerId")
fun loadItem( offerId: String): Flowable<Item>
```

With the Room DAO defined like this, if an item does not exist the `Flowable` will emit nothing. There will be no `onNext` events. Also defined as `Flowable` Room never emits `onComplete`.

`Flowable.concat` waits for the first `Flowable` to emit `onComplete` then subscribes to the second `Flowable` and emits all items.

Since [alpha5](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62231019) you can specify the return type in Room as `Maybe<Item>` so you can detect if there is an existing item in the db. Another option is to define the return type as `Flowable<List<Item>>` and Room will emit an empty list if the item does not exist in the DB.

If you switch Room to:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM offer WHERE id = :offerId")
 fun loadItem( offerId: String): Flowable<List<Item>>
```

you could do something like this (calls the API only if there are 0 items in the DB):

```
item1.flatMap { if(it.size == 0) item2 else Flowable.just(it) }
```

Note that this will end the stream if there is an error in the API call. Check the `onErrorXXX` operators to work around that.

Comment: Thanks,
I could not understand the difference
  @Query("SELECT * FROM item")
  fun loadItems(): Maybe<List<Item>>

 loadItems().toFlowable()


  @Query("SELECT * FROM item")
  fun loadItems(): Flowable<List<Item>>

I understand the difference between Flowable and Maybe,
but in this case they act differently ,but as the result both are Flowable

Comment: @A.A.I.A with `Maybe` you get the item (if exists) then the subscription completes. Even if you convert it to `Flowable` it will emit 0 or 1 items and then complete. With `Flowable` you get continuous notifications, the subscription never completes (unless you unsubscribe)